# Unique number generation within a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new and C#. i want to automatically generate a unique number inside a text box which i can use as a reference number to a form that does asset registration. this reference number will be used as a unique identifier to each asset registered and also given to the asset owner for reference's sake.

Comment: A really uniqe number is impossible

Comment: Where are you storing your assets? Because normally you would use a database, and the database would generate the unique ID. If you don't have a database, you could use a GUID, but that's not a number but a (fairly long) string.

Comment: Unique in which context? Use a database and an [`Identity` column](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_column).

Comment: am using SQL server 2008 and visual studio 2010. how can i retrieve the unique id from the database to my form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TimeStamp along with the new GUID.

```
  string uniqueKey = string.Concat(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssf"), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

If you really need a number intead of string as a unique key then you can use only time stamp with following stratergy.then it will unique with any given time,Lock to ensure that no two threads run your code at the same time. Thread.Sleep to ensure that you get two distinct times at the tenth of second.

```
static object lockerObject = new object();
static string GetUniqueKey()
{
    lock (lockerObject)
    {
       return DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssf");
       Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Or i found a way to do it without time stamp from [here](http://madskristensen.net/post/Generate-unique-strings-and-numbers-in-C) as follows.

```
    public long GetUniqueKey()
    {
        byte[] buffer = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();
        return BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

To do this, you can use a Guid (globally unique identifier) The chance that the value of the new Guid will be all zeros or equal to any other Guid is very low.

```
public static void Main() 
{
   Guid  g = Guid.NewGuid();
   Console.WriteLine(g);      
}
```

You cand find more about this here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Guid.

```
Guid temp;
temp = Guid.NewGuid();
textBox1.Text = temp.ToString().Replace("-", "");
```

But be aware. A real uniqe number generation is impossible.
There are other ways like the `Random` class

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the GUID's they are pretty easy to generate and reasonably unique?

```
// This code example demonstrates the Guid.NewGuid() method. 

using System;

class Sample 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
    Guid g;
    // Create and display the value of two GUIDs.
    g = Guid.NewGuid();
    Console.WriteLine(g);
    Console.WriteLine(Guid.NewGuid());
    }
}

/*
This code example produces the following results:

0f8fad5b-d9cb-469f-a165-70867728950e
7c9e6679-7425-40de-944b-e07fc1f90ae7

*/
```